# jQuery - Get tag text and output it, for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Input HTML

```
<h2>A random title</h2>
<h3>Another cool title</h3>
```

Desired HTML output

```
<h2 class="ghost" data-titre="A random title">A random title</h2>
<h3 class="ghost" data-titre="Another cool title">Another cool title</h3>
```

jQuery I'm using

```
var ghost = $('h2, h3');
ghost.attr('data-titre',ghost.text());
ghost.addClass('ghost');
```

Result I'm getting :

```
<h2 class="ghost" data-titre="A random title Another cool title">A random title</h2>
<h3 class="ghost" data-titre="A random title Another cool title">Another cool title</h3>
```

Comment: You could loop over `ghost` so you're not overwriting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the class, then use `attr` with a callback

```js
$('h2, h3').addClass('ghost').attr('data-titre', function() {
    return $(this).text()
});


console.log( document.body.innerHTML )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>A random title</h2>
<h3>Another cool title</h3>
```

Comment: Works great and not so much lines, thanks. I never think of using callback !

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each element to add the text and class.

```
var ghost = $('h2, h3');
ghost.each(function() {
 $( this ).attr('data-titre',$(this).text());
 $( this ).addClass('ghost');
});
```